# Override localstorage.setItem method LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, event, browser

I am trying to make the localstorage.setitem(key,value) method dynamic to do some custom stuff. But it doesn't seem to work? Is this supported in LWC framework?

Here is my HTML file

```
<lightning-button class="slds-m-left_xx-small,slds-m-top_large"
                                    variant="brand"
                                    name="reset"
                                    label="Reset" onclick={resetFlags} style="margin-left:5px">
                            </lightning-button>
```

and JS File is below

```
resetFlags(){
        const originalSetItem = localStorage.setItem;
        localStorage.setItem = function(key, value) {
            console.log(`I am inside the custom function`);
            const event = new Event('itemInserted');
            
            event.value = value; // Optional..
            event.key = key; // Optional..
            
            document.dispatchEvent(event);
           
            originalSetItem.apply(this, arguments);

        };

        localStorage.setItem("foo1", "bar1"); // Pops an alert
}
```

My basic goal is, when an event changes local storage on one browser tab it should be notified on the same tab to the same component but on a different salesforce tab. The above was the approach suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974084/listen-for-changes-with-localstorage-on-the-same-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked solution only works within the same browser tab. It's also generally unnecessary in modern code; just use `window.postMessage` to write a message to yourself if you're in the same tab, or use [lightning-message-service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation). If you want to message to a different tab, using `window.addEventListener('storage', handler)` and `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` should also work, as long as the components are in the same namespace.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, what I am trying to achieve is also for the same browser tab as well. I tried to use lightning message service. Our use case is in Service console app where you can open multiple Salesforce tab in one browser tab. I put my component (which is both publisher and subscriber to the channel) in two tabs. Loaded my components in both tabs and when I publish message in one tab the component in that tab is only able to read the message but not the component in the other tab. Not sure what I am missing here? Really appreciate your help

Comment: @Sfdxfox I figured the issue with LMS. I forgot to specify the scope of the published message to application_scope. Thanks for your help!